# "PDOException could not find driver" in laravel migration with postgresql

Tags: laravel

I have three databases for my project. When I try Laravel migration with PostgreSQL. I am getting some error. But Laravel migration with other mysql databases is okay. I am using **XAMPP**. Could you please check and correct me?

**Error**

```
[PDOException]
  could not find driver
```

**Database**

```
<?php

return [
    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql_shop'),
    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

        'mysql_cms' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_CONTAO_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_CONTAO_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_CONTAO_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_CONTAO_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
            'engine'    => null,
        ],

        'mysql_shop' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_SHOP_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_SHOP_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_SHOP_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_SHOP_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
            'engine'    => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_PGSQL_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_PGSQL_DATABASE', 'maindb'),
            'username' => env('DB_PGSQL_USERNAME', 'postgres'),
            'password' => env('DB_PGSQL_PASSWORD', 'postgres'),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => env('DB_PGSQL_SCHEMA', 'fes'),
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

    ],
```

**Migration Code**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePasswordResetsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('pgsql')->create('fes.password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('email')->index();
            $table->string('token')->index();
            $table->timestamp('created_at');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::connection('pgsql')->drop('fes.password_resets');
    }
}
```

**PHP INFO**
[image]

Comment: have you updated your .env file?

Comment: I have my env file and it is updated.

Comment: ok try to remove underscore from name convention mysql_shop to mysqlshop

Comment: I changed the name and tried but same result

Comment: try to run this code just to be sure that is it not laravel `if (!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME'))
    echo 'PDO driver unavailable';`

Comment: Result showing none. Yes, it's available

Comment: you have to many things in your database, try to put the original file back see if it works and try to added database driver one by one, I do not think I can help more at this stage

Comment: Thanks for the support.